# Getting Foreign Key Ids from Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue, I am not sure if I am going too far with my thinking or not, but the issue is I wanted to query sql server to give me foreign key Ids, column name and table for a specified primary key.
The below query gives me the primary key/foreign key constraint, tables, etc.

```
   SELECT 
    FK = OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id),
    Referencing_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id))
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)),
    Referencing_col = QUOTENAME(pc.name),
    Referenced_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)) 
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)),
    Referenced_col = QUOTENAME(rc.name),
    PK = pk.name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc
ON fkc.parent_object_id = pc.[object_id]
AND fkc.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS rc
ON fkc.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
AND fkc.referenced_object_id = rc.[object_id]
INNER JOIN (SELECT i.name, fk.[object_id]
  FROM sys.indexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS fk
  ON i.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
  AND i.index_id = fk.key_index_id
) AS pk
ON pk.[object_id] = fkc.constraint_object_id
ORDER BY Referencing_table, FK, fkc.constraint_column_id;
```

A simple table structure would be

```
create table test.ForeignTable1
(
  foreign_key_table_primary_key1 int primary key identity(1,1),
  randomdata1 varchar(200) not null
)

create table test.ForeignTable2
(
  foreign_key_table_primary_key2 int primary key identity(1,1),
  randomdata2 varchar(200) not null
)

create table test.PrimTable
(
   primary_key_column int primary key identity(1,1),
   ForeignTable1_data int foreign key references test.ForeignTable1(foreign_key_table_primary_key1) ,
   ForeignTable2_data int foreign key references test.ForeignTable2(foreign_key_table_primary_key2) 
)
```

The desired output of the sql statement would be to return be, for a particular primary key in **PrimTable**, it would return all the associated ids in **test.ForeignTable2** and **test.ForeignTable1** and show which table they come from.

If I supply 1, then it would return Ids (3,7,12) for **test.ForeignTable1** and (6,4,458,88) for **test.ForeignTable2**

Is it possible to query something like that? Also I was wondering how does sql server determine during a delete that you have a foreign key constrain in another table that is preventing you from deleting an item?

Comment: No information_schema table easier to use?

Comment: Of course it's possible to query as you have already done that :-) SQL Server stores constraint meta-data in the database and uses that to enforce referential integrity at execution time. That meta data is exposed via the catalog views your query uses, `INFORMATIION_SCHEMA` views, and catalog stored procedures.

Comment: Oh, you want to get the actual values from the related tables. That would be a job for dynamic SQL. Once you have the table and column names you'll need to assemble a `select` statement to retrieve the data, then use [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to run the query.

Comment: How do you plan on handling keys composed of multiple columns? Output all of the columns? Output a message respectfully declining to play along?

Comment: I am looking at a dynamic way to get info from the database about why I cannot delete a column in sql and give what values in what tables are preventing the deletion.

Comment: @HABO, so there is no sql function that exposes that functionality? or does SQL server use dynamic sql as well to query the data before it shows the foreign key violation?

Comment: The metadata in the database, exposed through the catalog and information schema views, tells you what the relationship between tables is, e.g. tables `Users` and table `Desks` both have a `UserId` column. If you want to know that `DeskId` `42` is preventing the deletion of `UserId` `9` then you'll need to get that from the tables themselves. You'll have to use _dynamic SQL_ by building the `select` statement on-the-fly, then execute it to get the specific values. The database engine is not limited to SQL functionality when it comes to _implementing_ SQL functionality.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that and though that SQL would return me the values without doing some magic coding

Comment: The good news is that you're retrieving all of the metadata (table and column names) from the database. As long as you continue using [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on all of the object names you don't need to worry about [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME=@PK_TABLE_NAME 
---- optional:
ORDER BY
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Deep, I am thinking that I may have been bad in asking the question, I am going to update it a bit to show an example of the expected output. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just run the following:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name = '<your_PK_table_name>'
```

Comment: Its just returning an empty rowset, is there something that I maybe missing?

Comment: Just checked now, after calling EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name='Table Name', @pktable_owner='Owner', @pktable_qualifier='Qualifier', it returns data,  but does not return the Ids of the foreign key table

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough and reply only the first part of your question. You should iterate the result of this sp (or your own query) and build a dynamic query to get the IDs. You should take into consideration multi field FKs, as well, as already stated.